# Where is the sample code for the Visual Studio 2010 extension to format code comments?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I was at PDC last year and saw a demo of an add-in for the next version of Visual Studio (2010), where the display of code comments for a C# code file had custom formatting.  I was under the impression that he code for this add-in was available somewhere, but I've not been able to find it anywhere.

The talk to which I'm referring was called:
Microsoft Visual Studio: Customizing and Extending the Development Environment

The item in question is on the PPT presentation and is in slide #29
[Power Point slide download](http://mschnlnine.vo.llnwd.net/d1/pdc08/PPTX/TL32.pptx).
Does anyone know if and where the sample code for this is available?

Answer (score 1):

The extension is available [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/0b439a8a-e21a-4e26-b82b-054fbf0acab7).  I don't know if source code is included.  But if not, reflector I'm sure will be enlightening.